# How to make python3 command run Python 3.6 instead of 3.5?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, environment-variables

I just downloaded Python 3.6.1, but when I type `python3 -V` in the terminal it's still `Python 3.5.3`. How can I make `python3` point to `Python 3.6`? All versions are in the `/usr/bin/` directory.

Comment: What do you mean with "downloaded"? Did you "installed" it? How?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3.6`

Answer (score 99, accepted):

do

```
rm /usr/bin/python3
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```

**much better solution**:

Damn, Python is used throughout much of Ubuntu for system scripts and software, and software relies on having Python (and the commands to start Python) in a certain spot. do back then.

```
rm /usr/bin/python3 
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

create alias in `~/.bash_aliases`

```
alias python3='/usr/bin/python3.6'
```

Scripts can then start with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python3.6': File exists`

Comment: You need to swap the arguments for `ln` to work: `ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: sorry :/ <code> ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3</code>

Comment: Correct, it worked with `ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: This solution actually broke my Ubuntu terminal. Something in the background is/was depending on `python3` pointing at `Python 3.5.3` and not `Python 3.6.1`. Not sure what, though.

Comment: Damn, Python is used throughout much of Ubuntu for system scripts and software, and software relies on having Python (and the commands to start Python) in a certain spot. 
do back then.<br/>
`rm /usr/bin/python3`
`ln -s /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3`
create alias in ~/.bash_aliases
`alias python3='/usr/bin/python3.6'`

Scripts can then start with something like:

`#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Answer (score 9):

Worked Perfectly...

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 6):

You could update the default python version system-wide using `update-alternatives` command.

```sh
$ sudo update-alternatives  --set python3 /usr/bin/python3.6
```

or you can also run the following command to choose among the various python versions installed on a host.

```sh
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for other than the accepted answer. Here is the solution that saved my life. This is to replace it with new version.

```
$ python3 --version
  Python 3.5.2

$ ls -lh /usr/bin/python3
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 23  2016 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5

$ sudo mv /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/_python3
$ sudo cp /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3

$ python3 --version
  Python 3.6.11
```

Answer (score 3):

first step

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```

second step

vim .bashrc

```
alias python3='/usr/bin/python3.6'
```

Answer (score -1):

- Method 1:

  ```
  pip install virtualenv
  virtualenv name_of_project
  ```
- Method 2

  ```
  py -3 -m venv name_of_project
  ```

Comment: - pip install virtualenv
*  - virtualenv envname  or  py -3 -m venv name_of_project